# How to Position Read More link after post excerpt?

Tags: css

I want to place read more link just beside post excerpt in WordPress. can any one please guide me. am using Ad-Sense Theme of mythemeshop. here is the example for my requirement 
[image]

plese provide css code to display read more link after post excerpt

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your function.php file of your theme.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">' . __('Read more..', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Refercence URL: http://www.dhirenpatel.me/display-read-link-wordpress-excerpts/